# Evaluation of an integral of some expressions involving fractions

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am stuck in evaluating the following integral:
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{b-a} \frac{1}{\sqrt{u} (a+u)} \,du,
\end{equation}
where $0<a<b$. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want $\sqrt{u(a+u)}$ or $(\sqrt u)(a+u)$? Just making sure...

Comment: just $\sqrt{u} (a+u)$.

Comment: But the answer I get should involve arccos.

Comment: Partial fractions is generally not useful with $\sqrt u$ in the denominator, but you can make the expression rational by letting $u=t^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\int_0^{b-a} \frac{1}{\sqrt{u} (a+u)} \,du
$$

If $w=\sqrt{u}$ then $w^2=u$ so $2w\,dw=du$, and you have
$$
\int_0^{b-a} \frac{1}{\sqrt{u} (a+u)} \,du = \int_0^{\sqrt{b-q}} \frac{1}{w(a+w^2)} (2w\,dw) = \int_0^{\sqrt{b-a}} \frac{2\,dw}{a+w^2}
$$
and you get an arctangent.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=t^2$, then the integral becomes:

$$\int_0^{\sqrt{b-a}} \frac{2dt}{a+t^2} $$ which is relatively easy to do, using that $\int \frac{dt}{1+t^2} = \arctan t + C$.